# Título da página e post randômico afeta a posição nos resultados de buscas?

Tags: html, seo

Tenho um tema com uma única página e várias atualizações são feitas por dia nesta página inclusive no titulo, queria estar bem colocada nos resultados de buscas sei que ha várias técnicas existem para isso... enfim quero saber se o título e conteúdo aleatório é bom ou ruim ou não faz diferença depende mesmo da palavra chave.

Comment: Está querendo saber se isso é considerado conteúdo duplicado pelo Google?

Comment: Não exatamente! é mais a questão do título mesmo; ajuda ou atrapalha o posicionamento se ficar mudando a tag <title>Texto Aleatório Aqui</title>

Comment: Se você alterar o título da página constantemente, tanto seus usuário quanto os mecanismos de busca ficarão confusos e consequentemente você perderá posições. Acredito que `<link rel=”canonical” href=”seu-site.html”/>` possa resolver esses problemas. Não publico uma resposta pois não sei muito sobre o assunto e sobre a utilização do atributo `canonical`.

Comment: Valeu vou procurar mais sobre o assunto

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que afete sim, pois os robôs do Google levam muito em consideração a questão conteúdo.

O ideal é que o seu título tenha relação direta com o conteúdo e que este conteúdo tenha sido produzido por você mesmo, ou por quem for alimentar o site.
Se eu não me engano, até os cabeçalhos de nível 3 são vistos pelo Google.
Outra coisa bem importante é cuidar com repetição de conteúdo. Por exemplo: Se você estiver pegando conteúdo de outros locais e só dando Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V, o Google vai descobrir.

Espero ter ajudado! =)

Answer (score 0):

A tag de título deve estar correlacionada com o conteúdo interno, então se voce altera o conteúdo deve alterar também o title para indicar sobre o que fala o  conteúdo interno da página. Na verdade é o contrário se você altera a pagina e não altera o title aí está um problema para o google interpretar como será indexada esta pagina. Se o seu conteúdo fala de tudo e não só o que está no título aí também encontra-se um problema para melhor rankeamento. Isso não quer dizer que você estará mal rankeada porque o ranking é composto de vários outros fatores, esse é apenas um deles, ajudar ao google dando o título certo ao conteúdo da página é uma boa estratégia.